# vba how to define a two way enum

Tags: vba, enums, ms-word, bit-manipulation

I have a user Form that has a combo box in it `Comb_colorPick_Change`, each item in the combo box represents a color as in this picture

[image]

I defined an enum which stores some word color constants (`wdRed`, `wdGreen`, …etc), I wanted to change the back color of the combo box using a bitwise operation (AND) between the Sum of all enum constants (all) and the combobox item index `Comb_colorPick.BackColor = (Comb_colorPick.ListIndex + 1) And All`, this operation results a number (ex: 3) which corresponds to a color (ex: `wdRed`) **BUT** I need the result number to be (wdRed) instead of (3). i used select case before to change the back color but i'm looking for another method

**My main question is:**

How do I define a two way enum where I can get a number by providing a constant name and vice versa.

**my other questions**

- Is it possible to loop through a public enum, ex: WdColor enum
- How to use “bitwise enumerations”, a practical example would be
     appreciated

**Here is my code:**

```
Private Enum MyColors
    Red = wdRed
    Green = wdGreen
    Blue = wdBlue
    Yellow = wdYellow
    Turquoise = wdTurquoise
    BrightGreen = wdBrightGreen
    Pink = wdPink
    Violet = wdViolet
    All = wdRed Or wdGreen Or wdBlue Or wdYellow Or wdTurquoise Or wdBrightGreen Or wdPink Or wdViolet
End Enum

Private Sub Comb_colorPick_Change()

    Dim co As MyColors
    co = All
    'Comb_colorPick.BackColor = (Comb_colorPick.ListIndex + 1) And co    '<=== i need this to be a constant name
    Label1.Caption = "Bitwise Result = " & ((Comb_colorPick.ListIndex + 1) And co)

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
' fill the combo during user form activation event
    With Comb_colorPick
        .AddItem "Red", 0
        .AddItem "Green", 1
        .AddItem "Blue", 2
        .AddItem "Yellow", 3
        .AddItem "Turquoise", 4
        .AddItem "BrightGreen", 5
        .AddItem "Pink", 6
        .AddItem "Violet", 7
        .Value = "BrightGreen"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no built-in "two-way" enum in VBA.  You would define a function which when passed a string would return the enum value, and another which did the opposite.  Also:  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx - see "composite values" section

Comment: what about this [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukFxP35k0m4 ] , and for the link you sent , this is called bitmasks as i believe i know how to use it but i don't think I'm using it as i should, that's why i asked

Comment: Flag enums work better when their values are powers of 2. Like, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, etc. ...otherwise you can't bitwise-combine them and have a unique combination; 4+2 is 6, 5+1 is also 6.

Comment: @Mat's Mug, yes i know that but my main question is clear..